# Not able to get the user's location in iOS 8 using CLLocation Manager?

Tags: objective-c, dictionary, ios8, core-location, cllocationmanager

I tried to get the user's latitude and longitude but I got result 0.000000 - I have tried following code.

- I have assign the location manager variable.
- Location Manager allocated and set the delegate is self.
- Checked the iOS 8 version validation requesting.
- Using location start update location function.

Code:

```
locationmanager=[[CLLocationManager alloc]init];
locationmanager.delegate=self;
// check before requesting, otherwise it might crash in older version
if ([locationmanager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {

    [locationmanager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

}
[locationmanager startUpdatingLocation];

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"locations %@",locations);
    CLLocation*location = [locations lastObject];
    NSLog(@"location %f",location.coordinate.latitude);
}
```

> Result:2014-10-15 11:10:20.118 Good[714:25676] latitude 0.000000

Comment: Please edit your post to make it readable...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you have added the following lines NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription or NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in .plist file.

Comment: For some reason `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` was added to my plist as a `BOOL` by default. Location Services in my app were working as expected but selecting `Settings->MyApp->Privacy->Location Services` caused Settings.app to crash. Changing the type of value of `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` to a String (even without an actual value) fixed the crash.

Answer (score 2):

#define IS_OS_8_OR_LATER ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0)
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

```
[super viewDidLoad];
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

self.locationManager.delegate = self;
if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER){
    NSUInteger code = [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];
    if (code == kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined && ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)] || [self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)])) {
        // choose one request according to your business.
        if([[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription"]){
            [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
        } else if([[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription"]) {
            [self.locationManager  requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Info.plist does not contain NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription");
        }
    }
}
[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

}

> #pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        longitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        latitudeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }
}
```

> In iOS 8 you need to do two extra things to get location working: Add
>   a key to your Info.plist and request authorization from the location
>   manager asking it to start. There are two Info.plist keys for the new
>   location authorization. One or both of these keys is required. If
>   neither of the keys are there, you can call startUpdatingLocation but
>   the location manager won’t actually start. It won’t send a failure
>   message to the delegate either (since it never started, it can’t
>   fail). It will also fail if you add one or both of the keys but forget
>   to explicitly request authorization. So the first thing you need to do
>   is to add one or both of the following keys to your Info.plist file:

- NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
- NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription

Both of these keys take a string

> which is a description of why you need location services. You can
>   enter a string like “Location is required to find out where you are”
>   which, as in iOS 7, can be localized in the InfoPlist.strings file.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 8, this *code fails silently* i.e you won’t get any error or warning.

You need to do two extra things to get location working:

1. **Add a key to your Info.plist**
2. **Request authorization** from the location manager asking it to start.

Any one or both of below keys needs to be added in Info.plist file.

1. **NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription**
2. **NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription**

These are of String type and value can be any message description or empty.

Now you need to request authorisation for corresponding location method. Use any one of below calls :

1. **[self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]**
2. **[self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization]**